Connecting an FlutterFlow application to Apple Health and Google Fit services
Does anyone have any experience or information about the possibility of simultaneously connecting an FF application to Apple Health and Google Fit services (user's choice)? It is required to obtain data on the user's activity for the day (heart rate, steps, sleep quality). If not directly, can it be achieved using custom code.
I'm currently in the initial stages of considering the development of an app using Flutter Flow.
While I haven't begun any development work yet, I'm keen to gather as much information as possible before diving in. Despite searching extensively on the internet, I've been unable to find a definitive answer to my queries. Therefore, I'm reaching out to explore any insights or recommendations that could help me make an informed decision before commencing the development process. Your expertise or experiences with Flutter Flow would be greatly appreciated in guiding me on this journey.
